# JScript Print XML Document

Tags: xml, javascript

So let me apologize right up front. I'm not a PHP programmer, I'm a C# programmer. But I have to support a website that was written for my company in PHP and is falling apart. So here's my simple question:

I have the following code:

```
xml_doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xml_doc.async = false;
url = "./viewInvoiceXML.php?soh_id=<? echo($soh_id)  ?>";

xml_doc.load(url);
xmlObj = xml_doc.documentElement;
```

Later in the page, I'm displaying some XML nodes out. I'm needing to see all the XML thats returned so I can find the right nodes that need to be displayed.

How do I print to the page this xml_doc or xmlObj? I'd just like to see all XML (tags and all). Is this possible?

------------Update-----------------

Well, as many of you have point out, its JScript that might be creating the ActiveXObject.

If its JScript, then I'm needing a way in JScript to show me the XML information. I'm telling you, I don't know much about this website at all.

Here's the other code that is getting the information out of the XML node.

```
xmlObj.childNodes(1).childNodes(0).childNodes(6).text
```

Comment: The XML parsing part doesn't look like a PHP code, isn't it JavaScript?

Comment: Obviously not PHP or another server side language. ActiveX Objects are not concerned with server side. @Miles can you please give more details.

Comment: Maybe you can do (assuming this is JS) alert(url); and then look at the xml by opening that url in a web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in your code example PHP code and JScript code are mixed. Only  `<? echo ... ?>` is actual PHP. The rest is plain JScript which is output to the browser, where it's then interpreted.

**EDIT:** It's not [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), it's [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript). For example there's no `ActiveXObject` class in standard JavaScript.

Because of that you cannot use PHP to display the XML code. You have write something which will work in the browser. Try adding this:

```
<code>
  <pre>
    <script language="JScript">
     document.write(xml_doc.xml);
    </script>
  </pre>
</code>
```

Essentially this adds some fixed HTML tags (code, pre) and a JScript command to output a string to the HTML page. `xml` is a property provided by the XMLDOM object, which returns the XML source representation.

Answer (score 0):

`print_r($var)` or `var_dump($var)` should do you for output PHP variables.